# How to change audio speed without changing pitch?

Tags: python, audio, moviepy

I need to apply audio to video at certain time with certain duration, but some audio duration is bigger(or smaller) then needed. How to change speed of audio without changing pitch? I tried to change fps(by multiplying to division of needed duration to audio duration) but it is not work as I want.

```
original = VideoFileClip("orig.mp4")
clips = [orig.audio.volumex(0.3)]
subs = [] #some array
i = 0
for sub in subs:
    clip = AudioFileClip("\\temp{}.mp3")
    mult = clip.duration / (sub.end - sub.start)  + 0.00001
    clip = AudioArrayClip(clip.to_soundarray(buffersize=500, fps=24000/mult), fps=24000).set_start(sub.start).set_end(sub.end)
    clips.append(clip)
    i += 1

final = CompositeAudioClip(clips)
final.write_audiofile("final.mp3")
```

Comment: You need to change the pitch of the audio so that it sounds normal when played back at the different speed. This would be done by resampling the audio at a correspondingly higher or lower rate. Simple example: To play at double speed would require the pitch to be halved.

Comment: do  you need use a phase vocoder algorithm to time stretch your audio, this can be hard, It is mathematically complicated the development of this kind of algorithm

Answer (score 2):

you can use librosa module:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
import librosa, numpy as np

song, fs = librosa.load("song.wav")

song_2_times_faster = librosa.effects.time_stretch(song, 2)

scipy.io.wavfile.write("song_2_times_faster.wav", fs, song_2_times_faster) # save the song
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer put all relevents infos and remove the link ?

Comment: I just tried this on an mp4 and the resulting mp4 had no image, just audio.

Comment: song_2_times_faster = librosa.effects.time_stretch(song, 0.04)
TypeError: time_stretch() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @Ronalds Mazītis seems like the module has been updated, does librosa.effects.time_stretch(song, rate=2) work?

Comment: the problem was that files were stereo.. while they needed to be mono..

Answer (score -1):

Using wave: Change the sampling rate

```
import wave

CHANNELS = 1
swidth = 2
Change_RATE = 2

spf = wave.open('VOZ.wav', 'rb')
RATE=spf.getframerate()
signal = spf.readframes(-1)

wf = wave.open('changed.wav', 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(swidth)
wf.setframerate(RATE*Change_RATE)
wf.writeframes(signal)
wf.close()
```

Comment: Just change the sample rate is not the way, it will change the speed together with pitch...